# Macbook Finder prevents chrome from doing actions with command key

Tags: ios

I am new to Apple products but I seem to have an issue with my Chrome (and maybe other browsers as well). I've narrowed down the issue to be Finder. The problem is periodically and randomly the commands such as cmd+r,w and others just don't work and I have to manually press the reload button in my browser. But if I force-shut Finder then it goes back to as it should. It feels almost as if Finder is constantly being active and it acts as an overlay over my browser but then again I can do every other function in my browser. The problem occurs randomly out of the blue multiple times a day and the only solution so far I've found is to re-launch Finder. My setup is two monitor + the laptop screen if that helps.

Comment: When this happens, what is the app name in the upper left corner, in the menu bar? In other words, is Finder having the focus without you realizing it?

Comment: No, it still points to Chrome